# Tokenizing Text With a Phrase

Tags: rapidminer

I have text in a column and want to break it into chunks based on words existing in the text.

Say this is my text in one record:

```
 Alice: Hello Bob: Hi Alice: Coffee? Bob: Tea,please
```

I want to split this by all conversations Alice made and add it as a new attribute to the same records. Will look something like below.

[image]

Meaning all text associated with "Alice:" will be in one attribute and all text associated to "Bob:" will be in another attribute.
Can this be done in Rapidminer?

Comment: You could have an issue with tokenizing if either of them mention the other's name, unless you include the `"<name>: "`. It would be nice it they were line-delimited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it can be done in RapidMiner. You can do this in many ways using, or not using, the Text Processing extension (i.e. using Cut Document, Tokenize, etc.). But if it's already in a column, I would just use Split with a RegEx expression like Alice.* and then Pivot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="8.0.000">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="text:create_document" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Create Document" width="90" x="45" y="136">
        <parameter key="text" value=" Alice: Hello Bob: Hi Alice: Coffee? Bob: Tea,please&#10; Alice: Awesome Bob: Thanks! Alice: How's life? Bob: not bad"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="text:documents_to_data" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Documents to Data" width="90" x="179" y="136">
        <parameter key="text_attribute" value="text"/>
        <parameter key="add_meta_information" value="false"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="split" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Split (3)" width="90" x="313" y="187">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
        <parameter key="attribute" value="text"/>
        <parameter key="split_pattern" value="\n"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="transpose" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Transpose (3)" width="90" x="447" y="187"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="rename" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Rename (2)" width="90" x="581" y="187">
        <parameter key="old_name" value="att_1"/>
        <parameter key="new_name" value="text"/>
        <list key="rename_additional_attributes"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="split" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Split" width="90" x="246" y="34">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
        <parameter key="attribute" value="text"/>
        <parameter key="split_pattern" value="\s(?=[A-Za-z]+:)"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="transpose" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Transpose" width="90" x="380" y="34"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="de_pivot" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="De-Pivot" width="90" x="514" y="34">
        <list key="attribute_name">
          <parameter key="bar" value="text.*"/>
        </list>
        <parameter key="index_attribute" value="foo"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="split" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Split (2)" width="90" x="648" y="34">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
        <parameter key="attribute" value="bar"/>
        <parameter key="split_pattern" value="[:]\s"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="trim" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Trim" width="90" x="782" y="34"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Select Attributes (2)" width="90" x="916" y="34">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="regular_expression"/>
        <parameter key="regular_expression" value="bar.*"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="filter_examples" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="103" name="Filter Examples" width="90" x="1050" y="34">
        <list key="filters_list">
          <parameter key="filters_entry_key" value="bar_1.is_not_missing."/>
        </list>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="aggregate" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Aggregate (2)" width="90" x="1184" y="34">
        <parameter key="use_default_aggregation" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="attribute" value="bar_2"/>
        <parameter key="default_aggregation_function" value="concatenation"/>
        <list key="aggregation_attributes">
          <parameter key="bar_2" value="concatenation"/>
        </list>
        <parameter key="group_by_attributes" value="bar_1"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="transpose" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Transpose (2)" width="90" x="1318" y="34"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="rename_by_example_values" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Rename by Example Values" width="90" x="1452" y="34"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="filter_example_range" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Filter Example Range" width="90" x="1586" y="34">
        <parameter key="first_example" value="1"/>
        <parameter key="last_example" value="1"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Select Attributes" width="90" x="1787" y="34">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
        <parameter key="attribute" value="bar_1"/>
        <parameter key="invert_selection" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="true"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="replace" compatibility="8.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Replace" width="90" x="1921" y="34">
        <parameter key="replace_what" value="[|]"/>
        <parameter key="replace_by" value=" "/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Create Document" from_port="output" to_op="Documents to Data" to_port="documents 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Documents to Data" from_port="example set" to_op="Split (3)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Split (3)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Transpose (3)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Transpose (3)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Rename (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Rename (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Split" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Split" from_port="example set output" to_op="Transpose" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Transpose" from_port="example set output" to_op="De-Pivot" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="De-Pivot" from_port="example set output" to_op="Split (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Split (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Trim" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Trim" from_port="example set output" to_op="Select Attributes (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Select Attributes (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Filter Examples" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Filter Examples" from_port="example set output" to_op="Aggregate (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Aggregate (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Transpose (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Transpose (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Rename by Example Values" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Rename by Example Values" from_port="example set output" to_op="Filter Example Range" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Filter Example Range" from_port="example set output" to_op="Select Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Select Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_op="Replace" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Replace" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time @SGenzer

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are a Java developer. If you want to go down that route, this is the easiest way to parse the text. Of course, you may run into issues if the names contain spaces.

I added some additional text to demonstrate unknown people.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ChatMiner {
    private static final Pattern NAME_TOKEN  = Pattern.compile("^(?<name>\\w+):$");
    private static final String NAME_GROUP   = "name";
    private static final String UNKNOWN_NAME = "UNKNOWN";
    private static final String WHITE_SPACE  = "\\s+";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "Alice: Hello Bob: Hi Alice: Coffee? Bob: Tea,please James: Hello guys!";
        String[] names = { "Alice", "Bob" };
        Map<String, List<String>> map = parseChat(text, names);

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("%-8s: %s%n", entry.getKey(), quoteItems(entry.getValue()));
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, List<String>> parseChat(String input, String... names) {
        Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
        nameList.add(UNKNOWN_NAME);
        nameList.forEach(name -> result.put(name, new ArrayList<String>()));

        String[] tokens = input.split(WHITE_SPACE);
        String currentName = null;

        for (String token : tokens) {
            Matcher m = NAME_TOKEN.matcher(token);
            if (m.matches()) {
                if (nameList.contains(m.group(NAME_GROUP))) {
                    currentName = m.group(NAME_GROUP);
                } else {
                    currentName = UNKNOWN_NAME;
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (currentName != null) {
                List<String> words = result.get(currentName);
                words.add(token);
                result.put(currentName, words);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static String quoteItems(List<String> list) {
        return list.stream().map(s -> String.format("\"%s\"", s)).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Bob     : "Hi", "Tea,please"
Alice   : "Hello", "Coffee?"
UNKNOWN : "Hello", "guys!"
```

---

### Dynamic Approach

If you want, you could skip declaring names and dynamically generate the name map when you come along and find someone new.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ChatMiner {
    private static final Pattern NAME_TOKEN  = Pattern.compile("^(?<name>\\w+):$");
    private static final String NAME_GROUP   = "name";
    private static final String WHITE_SPACE  = "\\s+";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "Alice: Hello Bob: Hi Alice: Coffee? Bob: Tea,please James: Hello guys!";
        Map<String, List<String>> map = parseChat(text);

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("%-6s: %s%n", entry.getKey(), quoteItems(entry.getValue()));
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, List<String>> parseChat(String input) {
        Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        String[] tokens = input.split(WHITE_SPACE);
        String currentName = null;

        for (String token : tokens) {
            Matcher m = NAME_TOKEN.matcher(token);
            if (m.matches()) {
                String name = m.group(NAME_GROUP);
                if (!result.containsKey(name)) {
                    result.put(name, new ArrayList<String>());
                }
                currentName = name;
                continue;
            }

            if (currentName != null) {
                List<String> words = result.get(currentName);
                words.add(token);
                result.put(currentName, words);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static String quoteItems(List<String> list) {
        return list.stream().map(s -> String.format("\"%s\"", s)).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Bob   : "Hi", "Tea,please"
James : "Hello", "guys!"
Alice : "Hello", "Coffee?"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain in detail.